# Archive slack channels after 4 months of the last msg in channel

Tags: slack-api

I am looking for a way to archive slack channels after 4 months of the last msg in channel.

I have look at the apps in the store and the functions slack has. There wasn't a solution for my request. I need to make it myself but not sure if i need to make a bot or app with api.

The idea is when a channel name has extensions say  proj- in the name and the last msg in that channel is 4 months old. This channel need to be archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this: https://github.com/Symantec/slack-autoarchive

I created a short bash script to call the `slack-autoarchive.py` script and then called that from a cron job once a day:

```
export SLACK_TOKEN=[my token]
export WHITELIST_KEYWORDS="bicycles,codecoverage,kernel,storage"
export DRY_RUN=false
export ADMIN_CHANNEL=general
export DAYS_INACTIVE=120

cd ~/Programs/Symantec/slack-autoarchive
echo ==========================================
date
PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 python slack-autoarchive.py
echo 'Done!'
```

Answer (score 3):

## A possible sample in python

This isn't an official Slack API sample app or anything, but it's very similar to what you're describing - [Destalinator](https://github.com/randsleadershipslack/destalinator)

## Writing a basic script to achieve it

At a high level, what you want to do is very possible and shouldn't need to be too complex.

### Getting a list of channels

What you'll want to do is have a scheduled job on your server that pings [`conversations.list`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list). That endpoint will return an array of channels in the workspace. You can exclude already archived channels to make the list more manageable. Once you have that list, I'd suggest removing channels where `created` is less than 4 months old, once again trimming your list down.

### Getting the time of the last message

Once you've got your trimmed down list of channels, you'll want iterate over it, pinging [`conversations.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) on each channel, with the `oldest` argument set to your preferred time period, in this case 4 months.

If the response for a given channel contains an empty `messages` array, then the channel hasn't gotten any new content since the value given in `oldest`. Store this channel ID somewhere for later.

Once you've iterated over all the possible channels, you should have a smaller array which now only contains channel IDs with no content in the last 4 months.

### Archiving "stale" channels

The only remaining step is to archive them and we'll do that using the [`conversations.archive`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.archive) endpoint. The only arguments here are a `token` and a `channel`. So loop over your channels to archive array, hitting this endpoint for every entry.

With all that, you're done!

Comment: Thank! you this helps a lot